# Changes in terminology for Swift function parameter labels

Tags: swift, function, parameters, terminology

Swift provides the ability to give both an internal and external name/label for parameters of functions. But lately Apple seems to have resorted to only saying "Argument" and "Parameter" names/labels and dropped the use of internal/external to describe these things.

In the Swift documents, and WWDC videos, there are a few unclear efforts to describe the difference between a function's parameters and arguments, without referring to these as the outward facing or internal, [such as](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158):

> Each function parameter has both an argument label and a parameter
>   name. The argument label is used when calling the function; each
>   argument is written in the function call with its argument label
>   before it. The parameter name is used in the implementation of the
>   function. By default, parameters use their parameter name as their
>   argument label.

Imagine a `jump()` function.

Internally, the names of "when" and "height" might be different, and these are the internal names. External and internal don't seem to be at all confusing, other than the ordering in the Function Definition and then Declaration:

```
 func jump(_ who: String, whenToJump when: Float, howHigh height: Int){
        // wait for whenToJump
       // adjust who.y by howHigh
    )
```

Which of these is a parameter, in the sense Apple is referring to them, and which is an argument?

Comment: I know the mental difference, I'm wondering which is which in terms of conventions of terminology.

Comment: is a parameter (in this terminology) the external or internal?

Comment: @MartinR see this page, search for external or internal, it's not on the page, yet earlier versions of Swift documentation used the words internal and external: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158

Comment: Here's a description of Swift 3.0 Function Parameters and Argument Labels using 'external' and 'internal' to describe their nature: https://craiggrummitt.wordpress.com/2016/06/15/func-parameters-in-swift-3-0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is described in detail in the section 
*Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names*

in [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

Briefly, the differences between **Swift 2** and **Swift 3** are

- "External name" **(Swift 2)** is now "Function Argument Label" **(Swift 3)**
- "Internal name" **(Swift 2)** is now "Parameter Name" **(Swift 3)**
- In **(Swift 2)** the first parameter is `_ name` (internal, but no external) by default
- In **(Swift 3)** the first parameter is `name name` (function argument label and parameter name) by default.

Comment: So Function Argument Label is the First, and Parameter Name is the second. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: That's very odd. That's basically backwards from these terms' standard uses -- in C at least.

Comment: @JoshCaswell  I guess the Swift fathers haven't created Swift to be a superset of C

Comment: True enough, but there's a difference between distinguishing a similar concept by giving it a new name, and just reversing the existing names' meanings. I didn't think Swift was supposed to be a Marxist revolution. :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yeah... my mind wanted them the other way around, too. Was replaying videos and rereading Apple docs and going backwards in comprehension.

Comment: @JoshCaswell also, thanks for the edit. Much nicer wording. I was full of infuriation.

Comment: @SKOOP My apologies for English is not my native language.

Comment: No worries. You nailed it with your answer. Gave me the insight I needed to see what Apple is trying to say. It's very odd that they simply can't say "We've renamed this, this (argument label) is outward/external, this (parameter name) is internal/inward..". so there's zero confusion, or chance of confusion. But it seems I was the only person baffled by it.