# What are the new "for", "at", "in" keywords in Swift3 function declarations?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I'm working through a beginners' tutorial on Swift that is written in Swift 2.

It contains code like (random example)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
```

This has changed in Swift 3 (I'm using XCode 8 Beta), and the IDE helpfully converts this to the new (beautiful!) notation:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
```

What confuses me here is the  "for" in "for segue:". I get why it's there, but what kind of an element is it syntactically? Is the parameter named `for`,  `for segue`, or `segue`?

Is it mere decoration - an element with no meaning but to help the developer understand the context? Does it do anything else? Does the concept have a name? Can I use it in my own methods?

I see the same happening with "in" and "at".

Comment: syntax mistake? should be forSegue:, parameter label

Comment: @ShadowOf nope, it seems to be the new [Swift 3 way](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift3)

Comment: @El I get that, but what is it syntactically? Is the parameter named `for segue` or `segue` in the method? If it's `segue`, the `for` has to be defined somehow.

Comment: It was called "external parameter name" in Swift <= 2, and is called "argument label" in Swift 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410889/changes-in-terminology-for-swift-function-parameter-labels, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The syntax allow you to label arguments twice - once for use within the function (the *parameter name*) and once for use when calling (the *argument label*). By default these two will be the same (like with `sender` in your example), but they differ when it makes a function more readable at the call site:

```
prepare(for: aSegue, sender: something)
```

being more readable-as-a-sentence than:

```
prepare(segue: aSegue, sender: something)
```

Which sounds like you're preparing the segue, not preparing *for* the segue.

`for` would be a dreadful name to use internally in the function to refer to the segue, so you can use a different one if you require.

The idea is to meet the sometimes conflicting goals of readability at the call site and sensible naming in the implementation.

When defining a function, if you are going to use separate argument labels and parameter names, you specify the argument label first, and the parameter name second:

```
func sayHello(to name: String) {
    print("Hello " + name)
}

sayHello(to: "Pekka")
```

`to` only has relevance when calling the function. `name` is used inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

Those `for` and `at` are not reserved keywords in swift's parameter function, They are [Argument Labels](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/functions/#Function-Argument-Labels-and-Parameter-Names) that you can freely define which makes more sense to users of your function

Syntax

```
func prepare([ARGUMENT LABEL][PARAMETER NAME]: String) {}
```

Function Definition

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
   print(segue) //what your function scope knows
   // print(for) won't work, it's a label for function usage readability
}
```

Function call

```
prepare(for: mySegue) //with argument label 
prepare(segue: mySegue) //without argument label
```